# what's wrong with my sum query in model php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

here's my model code :

```
function total($id)
    {
        $this->db->select_sum('score');
        $q = $this->db->get('my_table');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->group_by('id');
        return $q->row()->score;  

    }
```

why the output still sum all of row not the specific row with id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$this->db->get()` actually *runs* the query.  You need to call that last.

```
function total($id)
    {
        $this->db->select_sum('score');
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $this->db->group_by('id');

        $q = $this->db->get('my_table');
        return $q->row()->score;  

    }
```